# How to implement asynchronous data streaming in .Net Core Service Bus triggered Azure Function processing huge data not to get OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, azure-functions, streaming, azureservicebus

I have a **service bus triggered Azure Function** which listens for messages containing just blob URL strings of JSON data which each one of them is **at least 10MB**.

Message queue is near real-time(If I use the correct term) so producers keep putting messaging to the queue with a frequency so there is always data in the queue to be processed.

I have designed a solution but it gets `OutOfMemoryException` most of the time. The steps involved in the current solution sequentially are:

1. Consume a message
2. Download the file from the URL within the consumed message to a temporary folder
3. Read the whole file as a string
4. Deserialize it to an object
5. Partition into the chunks to supply Mongo bulk upsert limit
6. Bulk upsert to Mongo

I have tried to solve `OutOfMemoryException` and I thought that it's because my function/consumer don't have the same pace with the producer, so I think that **at the time t1 when it gets the first message** and process it and then while it's upserting to the mongo the function keeps getting the messages and they accumulate in the memory and waiting to be upserted.

**Is my reasoning right?**

Thus I think that If I could implement a streaming solution starting from #3, reading from file by chunking and putting it to a stream then I would prevent the memory keep growing and reduce time also. I have mostly Java background and I somehow know that with `custom iterator/spliterator/iterable` it is possible to do streaming and asynchronous processing.

**How can I do asynchronous data streaming with .Net Core in an Azure Function?**

**Are there other approaches to solve this problem?**

---

```cs
namespace x.y.Z
{
    public class MyFunction
    {
        //...

        [FunctionName("my-func")]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("my-topic", "my-subscription", Connection = "AzureServiceBus")] string message, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            var data = new PredictionMessage();

            try
            {
                data = myPredictionService.genericDeserialize(message);
                await myPredictionService.ValidateAsync(data);
                await myPredictionService.AddAsync(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}

public class PredictionMessage
    {
        public string BlobURL { get; set; }
    }

namespace x.y.z.Prediction
{
    public abstract class BasePredictionService<T> : IBasePredictionService<T> where T : PredictionMessage, new()
    {
        protected readonly ILogger log;
        private static JsonSerializer serializer;


        public BasePredictionService(ILogger<BasePredictionService<T>> log)
        {
            this.log = log;
            serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        }
        public async Task ValidateAsync(T message)
        {
            //...
        }

        public T genericDeserialize(string message)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message);
        }

        public virtual Task AddAsync(T message)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<string> SerializePredictionResult(T message)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".json");
                Uri srcPath = new Uri(message.BlobURL);

                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(srcPath, tempPath);

                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(tempPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
                    {
                        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    File.Delete(tempPath);
                });

                return result;
            }
        }

        protected TType StreamDataDeserialize<TType>(string streamResult)
        {
            var body = default(TType);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(streamResult)))
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    body = (TType)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(TType));
                }
            }

            return body;
        }


        protected List<List<TType>> Split<TType>(List<TType> list, int chunkSize = 1000)
        {
            List<List<TType>> retVal = new List<List<TType>>();

            while (list.Count > 0)
            {
                int count = list.Count > chunkSize ? chunkSize : list.Count;
                retVal.Add(list.GetRange(0, count));
                list.RemoveRange(0, count);
            }

            return retVal;
        }
    }
}

namespace x.y.z.Prediction
{
    public class MyPredictionService : BasePredictionService<PredictionMessage>, IMyPredictionService
    {
        private readonly IMongoDBRepository<MyPrediction> repository;

        public MyPredictionService(IMongoDBRepoFactory mongoDBRepoFactory, ILogger<MyPredictionService> log) : base(log)
        {
            repository = mongoDBRepoFactory.GetRepo<MyPrediction>();
        }

        public override async Task AddAsync(PredictionMessage message)
        {
            string streamResult = await base.SerializePredictionResult(message);

            var body = base.StreamDataDeserialize<List<MyPrediction>>(streamResult);

            if (body != null && body.Count > 0)
            {
                var chunkList = base.Split(body);

                await BulkUpsertProcess(chunkList);
            }
        }

        private async Task BulkUpsertProcess(List<List<MyPrediction>> chunkList)
        {
            foreach (var perChunk in chunkList)
            {
                var filterContainers = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();
                var updateContainer = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();

                foreach (var item in perChunk)
                {
                    var filter = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    var update = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    filter.Add(/*...*/);
                    filterContainers.Add(filter);

                    update.Add(/*...*/);
                    updateContainer.Add(update);
                }

                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await repository.BulkUpsertAsync(filterContainers, updateContainer);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind scale up the plan of your function app ? It seems the memory is not enough, you can scale up to a higher plan.

Comment: @HuryShen thank you, but that option is evaluated and currently we want to solve this by using current resources effectively. However if you are talking about the `function orchestration` solution that one of my colleague mentioned he had heard a term like that saying that move the logic of mongo operations to a new azure function and put the chunked data to new service bus to pass them to new function, but we have evaluated that but it also seems like same data streaming solution that I want to implement in original function. In the end we would like to solve this in the single function.

Comment: In addition, currently memory peaks over 1GB, so do you think that scaling up the plan of single function with that memory is good practice or suitable one?